# I am getting the output for the program but not in the required way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

Write a Python function that accepts a string as an input.
The function must return the sum of the digits 0-9 that appear in the string, ignoring all other characters.Return 0 if there are no digits in the string.

my code:

```
user_string = raw_input("enter the string: ")
new_user_string = list(user_string)
addition_list = []
for s in new_user_string:
    if ( not s.isdigit()):
        combine_string = "".join(new_user_string)
        print ( combine_string)
    else:
        if ( s.isdigit()):
            addition_list.append(s)
            test = "".join(addition_list)
            output = sum(map(int,test))
            print ( output )
```

the output should be:

```
Enter a string: aa11b33
8
```

my output:

```
enter the string: aa11b33
aa11b33
aa11b33
1
2
aa11b33
5
8
```

Answer (score 4):

This look suspiciously like homework...

```
getsum = lambda word: sum(int(n) for n in word if n.isdigit())

getsum('aa11b33')
Out[3]: 8

getsum('aa')
Out[4]: 0
```

An explanation of how this works piece-by-piece:

1. The function `n.isdigit()` returns `True` if `n` is composed only of one or more digits, false otherwise. ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit))
2. The syntax `for n in word` will loop over each item in the iterable `word`. Since `word` is a string, python considers each character to be an individual item.
3. The operation `sum(int(n) for n in word...)` casts each character to an `int` and takes the sum of all of them, while the suffix `if n.isdigit()` filters out all non-digit characters. Thus the end result will just take the sum of all the individual digit characters in the string `word`.
4. The syntax `lambda x: some expression using x` constructs an anonymous function which takes some value `x` as its parameter, and returns the value of the expression after the colon. To give this function a name we can just put it on the right-hand-side of an assignment statement. Then we can call it like a normal function. Usually it's better to use a normal `def getsum(x)` kind of function definition, however `lambda` expressions are sometimes useful for if you have a one-off kind of function you just need to use as a parameter to a function. In general in python it's better if you can find a way to avoid them, as they're not considered very readable.

Here is a complete example:

```
def sumword(word):
    return sum( int(n) for n in word if n.isdigit() )

word = raw_input("word please: ")
print(sumword(word))
```

Comment: its from python coding challenge that i am trying.

Comment: Since it's obviously homework/coding challenge material, doesn't it make sense to post a detailed explanation of what he was doing wrong, rather than just pasting in the correct answer with no explanation?

Comment: @machineyearning yes it does. Other answers have that now, though, so I'm just going to leave mine up as an alternative way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Ben, however, I am curious as to why yours works, I don't completely understand the line of code in your function; yours is much more efficient than mine, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Ben Oops, I just edited the post with an explanation since I though you were done. Feel free to delete mine if you think yours is better.

Comment: @machineyearning Eh, yours is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
user_string = raw_input("enter the string: ")
new_user_string = list(user_string)
addition_list = []
for s in new_user_string:
    if ( not s.isdigit()):
        combine_string = "".join(new_user_string)
    else:
        if ( s.isdigit()):
            addition_list.append(s)
            test = "".join(addition_list)

output = sum(map(int,addition_list))
print output
```

You were getting the output you were for two reasons.

1. In the if statement, you were telling it to print the string that was originally inputted when it came across a non-digit. This makes perfect sense as you look at your output - the string is printed when it sees a, the string is printed when it sees the second a, and the string is not printed, not printed (for the ones) and then the string is printed for the last time with the b.
2. You were printing the output as the for loop incremented through the list, meaning it printed the total each time. Moving the output variable and print statement outside the for loop fixed the problem.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Python cares about indentations:

```
user_string = raw_input("enter the string: ")
new_user_string = list(user_string)
addition_list = []
for s in new_user_string:
    if ( not s.isdigit()):
        combine_string = "".join(new_user_string)
        #print ( combine_string)
    else:
        if ( s.isdigit()):
            addition_list.append(s)
            test = "".join(addition_list)
            output = sum(map(int,test))
print ( output )   #<------ change here
```

Also got rid of your inside print statement since it's not your output.